# custom payment module is not showing in checkout (frontend)

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-methods

i need help for payment method, is showing on the backend but not in the frontend
this is the url for the module that am using

http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/

can please somebody help me with this..(magento 1.7.0.2)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Model/Standard.php, add one more protected variable,

`protected $_canUseCheckout = true;`

This should show the payment method in frontend.

FYI, `$_canUseInternal` when set is used to display payment method in backend.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replay.. i added the variable, but nothing happens, another advice ? :)

Comment: Ohh ok. Have you gone through the comments in that tutorial? Seems someone else also experienced same and he resolved by disabling compilation and clearing cache.

Comment: yes, the compilation was the problem...thank you so much ... ..all the best :)